# WebTestClient check that jsonPath contains sub string

Tags: java, spring-test, reactive

In MockMvc there is an ability to assert that jsonPath contains substing

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.error.message")
.value(containsString("message")))
```

I wonder if there a nice way to do the same for WebTestClient, the syntax is a bit different

```
webClient.post().uri("/test")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(Mono.just(MyRequest), MyRequest.class)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isBadRequest()
                .expectBody()
                .jsonPath("$.message").isEqualTo("message")
```

But I've found only isEqualTo method that related to it.

It could be done with exctracting getBodyAsString() from WebTestClient.BodyContentSpec but it doesn't look good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is currently (*as of Spring Framework 5.0.4*) no support for Hamcrest matchers for use with `WebTestClient`.

However, you can use a regular expression to test if a JsonPath exists where an element *contains* a given substring.

For example, I just verified the following in Spring's own test suite. Note that the `/persons` URL returns a list of person objects (i.e., `new Person("Jane"), new Person("Jason"), new Person("John")`) and that the `Person` class has a `name` property.

```java
this.client.get().uri("/persons")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus().isOk()
        .expectBody()
        // The following determines if at least one person is returned with a
        // name containing "oh", and "John" matches that.
        .jsonPath("$[?(@.name =~ /.*oh.*/)].name").hasJsonPath();
```

Thus, for your use case, I assume the following might work:

`.jsonPath("$[?(@.error.message =~ /.*substring.*/)].error.message").hasJsonPath()`

Another option would be to use `consumeWith(...)` instead of `jsonPath(...)` and then use Spring's `JsonPathExpectationsHelper` directly (which is what `MockMvc` uses internally).

Please let me know what works for you.

p.s. [SPR-16574](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16574) may potentially address this shortcoming in Spring 5.x.

Comment: Actually I did it in ugly way), just extracted all the response in WebTestClient.BodyContentSpec converted it to message and parsed it for substring. .hasJsonPath() - actually doesn't work because there is no such method available in this context

Comment: What do you mean "there is no such method method available in this context"? I tested it here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/00fea23e6b47829f0be7e603c0ba023c5763796f

Comment: FYI: I created the following JIRA issue to improve this for Spring 5.1: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16574

Comment: Thanks, it works, i just used old spring boot version

Answer (score 6):

Check out the following example for discovering how to perform rest API tests using WebTestClient:

```
testClient.post().uri(URL,"value")
            .header("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Utils
                    .encodeToString((loginInner + ":" + passwordInner).getBytes(UTF_8)))
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus()
            .isEqualTo(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
            .expectBody()
            .jsonPath("$.value_A").isEqualTo("100")
            .jsonPath("$.value_B").isEqualTo("some text")
            .jsonPath("$.value_C").isNotEmpty();
```

Comment: I am using Spring Boot 2.7.5 and this works just fine.  The currently selected correct answer might work but it is much more complicated and much more difficult to read.

Answer (score 5):

As of Spring Framework 5 (not sure which version) the following can be used:

```
.jsonPath("message")
                .value(Matchers.containsString(<your_string>));
```

Comment: The correct answer

Answer (score 3):

WebTestClient WebFlux Spring Boot 2.3.4:

```
wtc.post()
   .uri(CREATE_ACCOUNT_URL)
   .contentType(APP_MEDIA_TYPE)
   .accept(APP_MEDIA_TYPE)
   .bodyValue(json)
   .exchange()
   .expectStatus().isBadRequest()
   .expectBody()
   .consumeWith(this::dumpToScreen)
   .jsonPath("$.timestamp").isNotEmpty()
   .jsonPath("$.path").isEqualTo(CREATE_ACCOUNT_URL)
   .jsonPath("$.status").isEqualTo(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value())
   .jsonPath("$.error").isEqualTo(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.getReasonPhrase())
   .jsonPath("$.message").isEqualTo(WebExchangeBindingException.MESSAGE)
   .jsonPath("$.reason").exists()
   .jsonPath("$.reason.size()").isEqualTo(2)
   .jsonPath("$.reason.password.size()").isEqualTo(1)
   .jsonPath("$.reason.password").isEqualTo(EXC_MSG_NOT_NULL)
   .jsonPath("$.reason.email.size()").isEqualTo(1)
   .jsonPath("$.reason.email").isEqualTo(EXC_MSG_NOT_NULL);
   // When having more than 1 message
   //.jsonPath("$.reason.email").value(containsInAnyOrder(EXC_MSG_NOT_NULL, EXC_MSG_NOT_BLANK));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem that my response body was plain text, not JSON and neither

`.jsonPath("$[?(@ contains 'my substring')]").exists()`  nor

`.jsonPath("$[?(@ =~ /.*my substring.*/)]").hasJsonPath()` returned a value.

So I fetched and processed the body manually:

```
ResponseSpec resp = testClient.get().uri(myUrl).exchange();
resp.expectBody(String.class).consumeWith(respBody -> {
    assertTrue(respBody.getResponseBody().contains("my substring"));
});
```